# Interpretation of stopping time sigma algebra (as explained in Durret)

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading Rick Durret's "Probability Theory and examples". The book is available online here [ https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf ]. Please refer to the definition cum interpretation of the sigma algebra associated with a stopping time which appears in the book  following Example 4.1.4 on page 156.

I understand the mathematical definition of $F_N$, but I wish to know the interpretation of this. I don't quite understand Durret's explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This is definitely a tricky thing to wrap one's mind around. In what follows, $n$ is supposed to be an integer, and $\tau$ an arbitrary stopping time.

How I think of it is as follows: for each $n$, we have a sigma algebra $F_n$. Thus we have a "decomposition" of the sigma algebra $F$, with each element of the decomposition being its own sigma algebra $F_n$.

Our goal is the following: to form a new decomposition which is "compatible" with the stopping time $\tau$, and use this decomposition to define a sigma algebra compatible with $\tau$.

Note  that the notion of being compatible with $\tau$ will depend on the time, hence why we split up the filtrations by each $n$ and consider how to make each $F_n$ individually compatible with $\{ \tau =n\}$.

Thus, for each $n$, in order to form this new compatible decomposition, we form a new <strike>sigma algebra</strike> collection of sets $\tilde{F}_n = " \{\tau =n  \}\cap F_n"$. By this I mean $\tilde{F}_n = \{ A \cap \{ \tau = n \} |\ A \in F_n   \}$.

Why would we do this? Because we only want to consider events for which $\tau$ is measurable, otherwise our sigma algebra would not be compatible with $\tau$. Thus we only consider events for which $\tau$ is measurable *and* which are contained in the information provided by the original decomposition. The logical "and" here means that we have to take set intersection, hence why intersection is used to form a decomposition compatible with $\tau$.

As one final step, we also have to create the "sigma algebra at infinity" $\tilde{F}_{\infty}$ formed by the limit of the filtration $F$ as well as the event $\{  \tau = \infty\}$. (EDIT 1.5 years later: I think this means $$\tilde{F}_{\infty} := "\{\tau = \infty\} \cap \bigcup\limits_{n \ge 1} F_n " := \left\{ A \cap \{\tau = \infty\} \left| A \in \bigcup\limits_{n \ge 1} F_n \right. \right\} $$

Then $F_{\tau}$ is the smallest sigma algebra formed by combining all of the collections of sets $\tilde{F}_n$ ($\forall n$) and $\tilde{F}_{\infty}$. We take the smallest sigma algebra containing all of the compatible <strike>sigma algebras</strike> collections of sets because we don't want any redundant information.

In other words, $F_{\tau}$ is formed by the "projections" or "traces" of each event $\{\tau=n\}$ onto each sigma algebra $F_n$ via intersection.

Comment: How is $\overline{\mathcal{F}_n}$ a $\sigma$-algebra?  For instance, it contains $\{\tau=n\}$ but not its complement?

Comment: @user3281410 I think you're right -- for example, even if it did contain $\{ \tau = n\}$ and its complement, there's no reason why it would contain $\Omega$, since $\{ \tau = n \} \cap \Omega = \{ \tau = n \}$ which would be a strict subset in any interesting case. Also Durrett only says "collection of sets", and there is probably a good reason for that. I am editing the post to fix the mistake, please let me know if any mistakes still remain.

Comment: @user3281410 The more I read this answer, the less sure I am that it agrees with what Durrett writes on p. 156. I wish I remembered my thought process when I wrote this 1.5 years ago, but I honestly don't. For now I will hold off on editing it more because it probably doesn't make sense for me to edit it if I don't understand it completely. All I remember is that I had stayed up all night working with someone on a homework assignment involving the stopping time $\sigma$-algebra several months before writing this answer, and the answer is similar to the resulting interpretation we came up with.